# Android achartengine horizontal bar charts looks compressed

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I have a bar chart that looks normal when displayed in vertical position, but if I use
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL)
To set the same chart to display charts in horizontal mode, it looks like this:
[image]

Its been compressed from top and bottom.

This chart is added to a vertical LinearLayout with about 0.3 of the weight of the total screen, I make it horizontal to make the most out of this LinearLayout, but the result isn't optimised.

Please help me, have you seen things like this before? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

A part of the codes that I used to configure the chart:

```
    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE); //does not support transparent
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL); //horizontal bar-graph

    renderer.setBarWidth(30f);

    renderer.setMargins(new int[]{15, 0, 65, 0}); //top, left, bottom, right. Since its a horizontal bar graph, the margins has been rotated clock-wise 
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.clearXTextLabels();
    renderer.setYLabels(0); //remove units on the Y axis(the horizontal axis since the graph has been rotated 90 degree)
    renderer.setXLabels(0); //removes 'values' from the X-Axis
    renderer.addXTextLabel(0.92, "Average");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1.1, "Maximum");

    renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setXLabelsAngle(0f);    
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(2);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
```

And add to the LinearLayout:

```
    LinearLayout barGraph1Layout = (LinearLayout) mainAct
                    .findViewById(R.id.bar_chart_layout);
    barGraph1Layout.removeAllViews();
    barGraph1Layout.addView(barChartView, new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And the LinearLayout:

```
<!-- PARENT LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GraphTitle1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- HORIZONTAL BAR CHART LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- OTHER LAYOUTS -->
```

**EDITED: PUTTING THE CHART IN A SCROLLVIEW**

In short, it still look the same.

I've modified the LinearLayout to host a scroll view to hold the chart, and set the renderer.setInScroll() to true, and changed the LinearLayout.addView section to ScrollView.addView, but the chart still look exactly the same.

**MODIFIED XML**

```
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/bar_chart_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show what are u doing?

Comment: yes, edited to show more details

Comment: Try dataRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.VERTICAL);

Comment: In my code, Orientation.VERTICAL is XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.VERTICAL, so that doesn't help.

Comment: At the moment I am using view.setScaleY(5) to stretch the GraphicalView back to correct aspect ratio, but setScaleY is not available until api 11 - honeycomb.

Comment: Is the above pic is after using setScaleX ?

Comment: The provided pic is before using setScaleY(not setScaleX, it doesn't matter in this case), after setting ScaleY to 5, it looks just like any other bar chart.

Comment: At the end I created a custom class and draw the bars myself, that's actually easier, compared to the many hours I tried to search a way to do so with achartengine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is better to make different XML files with same name for example abc.xml for landscape and abc.xml for portrait. It will better adjust your screen alignment

Comment: ehn, for the moment my activity is portrait only

Answer (score 0):

This is because of change in aspect ratio, you should keep this same .

Put ur graph in `scrollview` and use this to allow scroll .

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```

Or just use `portrait` mode .

Comment: Thanks for your advice, please see my edited question. I've tried portrait mode, it looks OK with the aspect ratio, only 1 thing: its too small. Since other elements occupy most of the screen, horizontal bar chart looks better in this case.